# using json.loads in python with an output from php json_encode

Tags: php, python, json

In my php script I've run the following

```
//PHP script to send json data to python
$t = new test();
$t->testname1 = $testname;
$t->jmx1=$jmx;
#$jsondata=json_encode($t);
$output=shell_exec('python /var/www/metro/run.py' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($jsondata)) );
```

Example of the json output as the following

```
"{"testname1":"fairul","jmx1":"1562638904.jmx"}"
```

I would like to use json.loads from the argument argv1 above in order to access it in python..

```
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
   data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])   
except:
   result = data['testname1']

# Send it to stdout (to PHP)
print json.dumps(result)
```

Not sure why i could only get NULL output

Comment: Have you seen what is in `data`?

Comment: Data looks okay....looks like php json.encode doesnt look right..        File "runtest.py", line 5
    data = json.loads("{"testname1":"fairul","jmx1":"1562638904.jmx"}"()
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You encoded the data *twice*; encode it just once:

```
$t->jmx1=$jmx;
$jsondata=json_encode($t);
$output=shell_exec('python /var/www/metro/run.py ' . escapeshellarg($jsondata) );
```

In Python, drop the blanked `except` handler, and move the setting `result` *out* of the exception handler. Here, I moved it into the `try` instead, catching either the `IndexError` when `sys.argv[1]` doesn't exist, `ValueError` thrown by a bad JSON string, `TypeError` when trying to index something that isn't a dictionary or the `KeyError` thrown for a missing key:

```
import sys, json

# Load the data that PHP sent us
try:
     data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])   
     result = data['testname1']
except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError, KeyError) as e:
     print json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
     sys.exit(1)

print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: thanks...looks like its invalid syntax,I guess php json.encode doesnt give the output required by python json.loads.. File "runtest.py", line 5
    data = json.loads("{"testname1":"fairul","jmx1":"1562638904.jmx"}"()
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @JohnFai: That is not valid Python; you cannot nest quotes without proper escaping. If you are going to use a literal JSON value, use single quotes around it at the very least.

Comment: hmmm..thought PHP escapeshellarg will cater for this scenario

Comment: @JohnFai: You posted code in a comment that looks as if you are putting the JSON value straight into a literal. It doesn't look much like what I posted as an answer; are you still using `sys.argv[1]` here?

Comment: opss sorry, yes I put the JSON value straight as part of the test..in any case my _sys.argv[1]_ doesnt seem to work yet

Comment: @JohnFai: I had to add a space after the path to the script, before the `escapeshellarg()` call. Perhaps that's missing?